# Combine multiple boolean columns into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am generation reports from an ERP system where users are provided with a check box which return a boolean value for each item selected. The database is hosted on SQL Server.

However, users can select **Contracts** with other values as well, as shown below.

[image]

I would like to capture the Categories as a single column and I don't mind having duplicate rows in the view. I would like the first row to return  **Contract** and the second the other value selected, for the same Reference ID.

[image]

Comment: Rows in a table or a resultset have no defined order without a column (or set of columns) to enumerate the desired order. Both suggestions skip over this fact - they might appear to work but that is an artifact of the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select distinct t.*, tt.category
from t cross apply
     ( values ('Contracts', t.Contracts),
              ('Tender', t.Tender),
              ('Waiver', t.Waiver),
              ('Quotation', t.Quotation)
     ) tt(category, flag)
where flag = 1;
```

Comment: Hello. How can we capture an additional category 'None' where Contracts, Tender, Waiver and Quotation are all 0?

Answer (score 1):

I guess a straightforward way is:

```sql
select *, 'Contract' as [Category] from [TableOne] where [Contract] = 1
union all select *, 'Tender' as [Category] from [TableOne] where [Tender] = 1
union all select *, 'Waiver' as [Category] from [TableOne] where [Waiver] = 1
union all select *, 'Quotation' as [Category] from [TableOne] where [Quotation] = 1
union all select *, '(none)' as [Category] from [TableOne] where [Contract]+[Tender]+[Waiver]+[Quotation] = 0
order by [Reference ID]
```

Note that the last line is put there just in case you need to handle the all-zero case.