# SQL function to concatenate Boolean variables

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean, concatenation

I am required to create a column that is a concatenation of 3 Boolean variables:

- Appetizer char(1) not null: Y/N
- Main char(1) not null: Y/N
- Dessert char(1)not null: Y/N

Such that if Y is indicated, the values will appear in a single cell.

For example, if Y is indicated for both main and dessert, it should appear as "Main Dessert" in the cell: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0vl3.png)

I've seen similar solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655079/combine-multiple-boolean-columns-into-a-single-column), but the answer returns duplicate rows, and unfortunately no duplication is allowed for my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain why `concat()` doesn't work.  Further, the question you have referenced is for SQL Server and the accepted answer is syntactically incorrect in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(Appetizer='Y', 'Appetizer ', ''),
              CONCAT(IF(Main='Y', 'Main ', ''), IF(Dessert='Y', 'Dessert ', ''))) FROM ...
```

This will give you the text for your column.  You may want to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',
                  CASE WHEN Appetizer='Y' THEN 'Appetizer' END,
                  CASE WHEN Main='Y' THEN 'Main' END,
                  CASE WHEN Dessert='Y' THEN 'Dessert' END) FROM ...
```